# How to display the content of the blob saved in the database without using paperclip or any gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, blob

I'm desperate enough to display the content of the blob from the database since I'm new to Rails.

I've already tried this:

```
#controller:
def show_image
   @user = User.find(params[:id])
   send_data @user.image, :type => 'image/png',:disposition => 'inline'
end
#views:
<%= image_tag url_for(:controller => "mycontroller", :action => "show_image", :id => @user.id) %>
```

but this is the output:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: In rails console, if you run `User.find(1).image` what do you get ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? Display an image? Putting `send_data` in your controller is going to allow a user to click on a link and *download* an image. It sends binary data and won't work with `image_tag`.

Comment: Yeah, display an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For more info on using the `image_tag` helper to display an image, check out [this documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag).

In your case, it looks like you have the name of an image stored in the `users` table (some kind of image associated with a particular user). You'll need to call that user attribute inside of `image_tag` like this:

`<%= image_tag @user.image %>`

Rails will look at the name of the image as stored in the database and try to find it inside of your `app/assets/images/` directory, so make sure that you've stored the image there. For example, if I have a user with "butterfly.jpg" as its `image` value, Rails will expect the file `app/assets/images/butterfly.jpg` to exist.

This is all you should have to do - no need for bringing controllers and `send_data` into it unless what you want to do is create a link that allows someone to download the image by clicking on it.

Comment: I ended up using paperclip, thank you btw @sixty4bit.